# Run batch file from Emacs

Tags: batch-mode

So, I've made a little batch file that simply compiles all the code I need and moves it to their right places. I've seen some people using the compile function  to launch something like the batch file I've made, but I can't seen to figure out how they do that. Also, I need the launch environment to be the same as the batch file is. This is the batch I have.

```
@echo off
mkdir ..\..\build
pushd ..\..\build
cl -Zi ..\alfa\code\win32_alfa.cpp user32.lib gdi32.lib
popd
```

There's also a second feature I would like to know if it's possible. Can I somewhat search the folders near where my code is and if it finds the build.bat, launch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, it's pretty simple, you use <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>, it prompts you for a command to use and you specify your script.

Comment: Oh, that really worked thanks. Btw, does the compile command launches from the file directory I'm editing? Can I just use some relative paths to launch that bat? I want to make my project as portable as possible, since sometimes I need to move a lot. Also, is it possible to make it search for the bat file, really don't know, maybe using lisp?  I want to keep this pattern to all my project, so each project will have a build.bat to make things quicker.

Comment: @GiovaniAbel: The default directory that the command is started with is the same as the file you were editing.  You can certainly run the script from somewhere else, by giving a path to M-x compile.  Making it automatically switch to another directory could be done two ways.  Doing it in lisp before launching the script is certainly possible, but a better way is probably to make the script do that.  You have nothing about what your system is, it seems to be some mix of UNIX and non-UNIX that I don't recognize.  BTW, the convention is when an answer works, the questioner should click the check.

Comment: Sorry, that check was really difficult to see (had to check on Questions how to mark it as answered :P). I'm actually on Windows, what's the best way to actually achieve this "search and run" script I want?